# Do clones have souls?

Tags: atma

Do animal and plant clones have souls? (Such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolly_(sheep))

Comment: Yes all living things have jiva atma's.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu how do clones get souls without copulation?

Comment: Who says copulation is needed?

Comment: Kauravas were born in jars, yet they had souls

Answer (score 4):

> Asya visramsamAnasya sharirasthasya dehinah |
>  DehAdvimuchyamanasya
>   kimatra parishishyate | Etadvai tath || - Katha Upanishad 2.2.4
>
> When, one, who is established in the body, as it's lord, gets detached
>   from the body, what remains in the body then? That is the AtmA.

So anything alive has the soul in it. Because the body is considered as dead or alive depending on whether the Atma is still attached to the body or not.

Comment: This question has no answer in Hinduism @rickross.  This question needs to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Gita makes it clear that AtmA resides in each jiva:

> 10.20 O Gudakesa, **I am the Self[AtmA] residing in the hearts of all beings**, and I am the beginning and the middle as also the end of (all) beings.

All means including animal and plant clones.